# Data repositories like UCI and mlData, for biological data

Tags: data-request, metadata, data-format, machine-learning

Are there any other data repositories like UCI and mlData, for biological data?? I want to know about mostly biological data set.(The format of data set would be like that of UCI)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many biology repositories, including [446 Biology data repositories](http://service.re3data.org/search/results/filter/?d=25&filter_subjects_active%5Bbiology%5D=Biology&term=) listed in the re3data repository catalog. Its not clear from your question how you want them to be similar to UCI, which seems to be a compendium.  The [KNB Data Repository](https://knb.ecoinformatics.org/) has a huge variety of biological data sets, some of which represent unique experiments and some of which represent synthetic data sets, such as the Global Population Dynamics Database (GPDD):

Prendergast J , Bazeley-White E , Smith O , Lawton J , Inchausti P , Kidd D , and Knight S. 2010. The Global Population Dynamics Database ([doi:10.5063/F1BZ63Z8](http://doi.org/doi:10.5063/F1BZ63Z8))